# CakePHP model save() not complete in time?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using CakePHP 1.3 with MySQL and run in a tight loop with code like:

```
if ($this->Model->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Model.name' => 'name'))) == 0)
{
    $this->Model->create();
    $this->Model->save(array('Model' => array('name' => 'name')));
}

$data = $this->Model->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Model.name' => 'name')));
```

However, at times $data comes out to be NULL; in other words, the record doesn't exist even though I do create/save a new record if it doesn't exist to begin with.

Is there some delay between the time the record gets created and when it is available?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1** I should point out that I do make sure the call to Model->save() succeeds before continue.

```
if (!$this->Model->save(array('Model' => array('name' => 'name'))))
    $this->error('Save failed');
```

Thank you.

Comment: TopQ, please post the complete code snippet. If you include the first and the second part, then you could save the same record twice, as *!$this->Model->save(...* is not just a simple check.

Comment: Could be something related to persistent connection. Are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, on MySQL level whenever the insert is finished, the newly created record can be used instantly. I've been using MySQL for years and I've never got this problem. As far as I know, the commands are added to a queue and are executed in a FIFO (First In First Out) system on default.

Comment: I used to write SQL queries directly and execute them and never ran into this kind of problems either. Must be Cake...

Answer (score 0):

You can always rewrite your code a bit:

```
if ($this->Model->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Model.name' => 'name'))) == 0)
  {
  $this->Model->create();
  if ($this->Model->save(array('Model' => array('name' => 'name'))))
    {
    $data = $this->Model->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Model.name' => 'name')));
    /* or better: */
    $data = $this->Model->findByName('name');
    /* or rather use: */
    $data = $this->Model->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Model.id' => $this->Model->id)));
    /* or even better, try this: */
    $data = $this->Model->read();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do check if the save succeeds or not. See my updated original post. Thanks.

Comment: Try `$data = $this->Model->read();`, it should retrieve the last inserted record.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some validation rules that are preventing to save, try this

```
if (!$this->Model->save(array('Model' => array('name' => 'name')))) {
    pr($this->Model->validationErrors);
}
```

if the pr() shows something, then you'll find the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do check if the save succeeds or not. See my updated original post. Thanks.